# Number of reduced binary quadratic form of determinant $d$ Is finite.

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

Number of reduced binary quadratic form of determinant $d$ Is finite

In the proof, book  consider positive and indefinite quadratic reduced form giving them upper bound and saying that it proves reduced quadratic forms are finite. But why we don't consider negative definite quadratic forms ? ( An Introduction to The theory of numbers - Ivan Niven , Theorem 3.19 )

I searched in the internet but didn't find anything that clarify it. I didn't add add the proof, because it only talks about upper bound of the positive and indefinite binary quadratic forms.

Comment: The count for negative definite is exactly the same for positive, there is a mapping $$ a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 \; \; \; \mapsto \; \; \; -a x^2 - b x y - c y^2 $$

Comment: @will Jagy, will positive and negative definite forms are equivalent? I think they aren't.  Am I right? Sorry for later response, it was night here. If you wish as that comment as answer, I will accept it. It clarify my doubt

Comment: There is a specific meaning for the word "equivalent" when discussing quadratic forms. It is not possible for a positive and a negative form to be equivalent